# How to filter a geojson file by geoid in Python?

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have a geojson file with coordinates for all the cities in New York. I want to create a plot for just New York City. How can I just access the coordinates of New York City by geoid using Python?

I tried the following as a stab in the dark, but it's not working.

```
selected_city = shape_geojson[shape_geojson['features']['properties']['geoid'] == location]
```

where location is the geoid for New York City and shape_geojson is the file with all the cities in New York.

Thanks

Snippet of geojson file:

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -73.743737,
              42.677112
            ],
            [
              -73.745489,
              42.670923
            ],
            [
              -73.743362,
              42.665549
            ],
            [
              -73.744124,
              42.663822
            ],
            [
              -73.743899,
              42.662171
            ],
            [
              -73.74166,
              42.660655
            ],
            [
              -73.74283,
              42.658936
            ],
            [
              -73.739429,
              42.656803
            ],
            [
              -73.730864,
              42.663279
            ],
            [
              -73.724964,
              42.670179
            ],
            [
              -73.723263,
              42.672879
            ],
            [
              -73.72619,
              42.673994
            ],
            [
              -73.743117,
              42.679323
            ],
            [
              -73.743737,
              42.677112
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "geoid": "14000US36001000100",
        "name": "Census Tract 1, Albany, NY",
        "B19013001": 32389,
        "B19013001, Error": 12524
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -73.761562,
              42.660941
            ],
            [
              -73.759932,
              42.659968
            ],
            [
              -73.761745,
              42.658177
            ],
            [
              -73.758936,
              42.657615
            ],
            [
              -73.750875,
              42.652557
            ],
            [
              -73.750045,
              42.654009
            ],
            [
              -73.749265,
              42.658246
            ],
            [
              -73.744909,
              42.662593
            ],
            [
              -73.744124,
              42.663822
            ],
            [
              -73.743362,
              42.665549
            ],
            [
              -73.745489,
              42.670923
            ],
            [
              -73.743737,
              42.677112
            ],
            [
              -73.747432,
              42.675943
            ],
            [
              -73.754544,
              42.670112
            ],
            [
              -73.757285,
              42.667655
            ],
            [
              -73.756117,
              42.666067
            ],
            [
              -73.761562,
              42.660941
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "geoid": "14000US36001000200",
        "name": "Census Tract 2, Albany, NY",
        "B19013001": 27714,
        "B19013001, Error": 3824
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -73.827854,
              42.696384
            ],
            [
              -73.830644,
              42.693262
            ],
            [
              -73.826398,
              42.692277
            ],
            [
              -73.820366,
              42.689707
            ],
            [
              -73.797692,
              42.676636
            ],
            [
              -73.794357,
              42.679764
            ],
            [
              -73.791654,
              42.681494
            ],
            [
              -73.78511,
              42.675781
            ],
            [
              -73.780354,
              42.671637
            ],
            [
              -73.771111,
              42.666475
            ],
            [
              -73.768212,
              42.669219
            ],
            [
              -73.776549,
              42.674177
            ],
            [
              -73.775161,
              42.676038
            ],
            [
              -73.780798,
              42.67876
            ],
            [
              -73.779046,
              42.681127
            ],
            [
              -73.771972,
              42.677627
            ],
            [
              -73.766066,
              42.673645
            ],
            [
              -73.761971,
              42.67166
            ],
            [
              -73.756276,
              42.671168
            ],
            [
              -73.754544,
              42.670112
            ],
            [
              -73.747432,
              42.675943
            ],
            [
              -73.743737,
              42.677112
            ],
            [
              -73.743117,
              42.679323
            ],
            [
              -73.751329,
              42.682088
            ],
            [
              -73.760237,
              42.684932
            ],
            [
              -73.758758,
              42.681655
            ],
            [
              -73.760831,
              42.680286
            ],
            [
              -73.765303,
              42.676379
            ],
            [
              -73.770573,
              42.678953
            ],
            [
              -73.768704,
              42.681288
            ],
            [
              -73.778006,
              42.685554
            ],
            [
              -73.778621,
              42.682985
            ],
            [
              -73.780093,
              42.681853
            ],
            [
              -73.786871,
              42.685061
            ],
            [
              -73.786575,
              42.686937
            ],
            [
              -73.792365,
              42.688278
            ],
            [
              -73.80031,
              42.689053
            ],
            [
              -73.800845,
              42.688439
            ],
            [
              -73.812687,
              42.690502
            ],
            [
              -73.816816,
              42.690936
            ],
            [
              -73.827854,
              42.696384
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way to do it is to create a new geojson object that only contains the feature data for New York City. Just make sure to include the outer structure that contains features.

I could show it by example if you include the actual data.

Comment: Thank you @zerOpRiME, I have added a snippet of the geojson data and also the image of the file when plotted. I just want to be able to access one of the polygons using the geoid as the filter.